# UL Classes dont work as I would like them to

Tags: html, css

I got 2 lists with different class but they dont work independent, both lists are unordered, class "menu" list is :  list-style-type: none; which is fine as it is my nav bar, but my second list which is "habilidades" doesnt show the little dots to the left, the only one that changed is the font family on my "Habilidades" class but I cant make the dots to appear

PS: Im starting to learn

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: 20%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu li a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.habilidades li {
  font-family: cursive;
  list-style-type: disc;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<section>
  <ul class="habilidades">
    <li>HTML</li>
    <li>CSS</li>
    <li>JavaScript</li>

  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, Does your screen look the same as the bottom-right window on this [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fqky20jt/)? In the example, it looks like there are list "dots" to the left of "HTML", "CSS", and "JavaScript" in the list. If your screen looks different, maybe something else in your HTML or CSS is causing the issue?

Comment: Hi!, It looked like this: https://imgur.com/a/7P6Czwq ----- But I was trying after being stuck for more than 1 hour haha, I fixed it, the issue was this little code: https://imgur.com/a/phUXqxO ---- After removing that code it got fixed and I got my dots on my second list :D Thanks!

Comment: Ah, glad to hear that you got it fixed! :) Sometimes it takes a while to figure out the problem with these types of issues!